# iPhone/iPad - how to get custom .IPA file onto device that is synchronized with other iTunes?

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, ipad, itunes, adt

I develop iPhone/iPad apps using the Adobe ADT tool. it compiles a .IPA file which needs to be loaded onto the device using iTunes.

Now - myself I own only a 3G iPhone. My friends sometimes lend me theyr devices for testing purposes.
For Apps developed with XCode, this is no problem. You just connect the device, add the provisioning profile to the device and load the app through XCode onto it.

But how to do it if I only have an .IPA file (plus provisioning profile of course). ITunes allows me only to load it to the device by synchronizing, but this will delete all the stuff my friends loaded onto theyr devices.

How can I test my IPA files and return the devices without any changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into this: http://testflightapp.com/

You can upload IPA builds for ad-hoc distribution and beta testing. You only have to click an "Install" link on the phone and it takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on over-the-air (OTA) setup. No sync necessary, just delete the app and the profile afterwards. iOS 4 and higher required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Iphone Configuration Utility from Apple to install and uninstall ipa files. It's available for Windows and MacOS.

windows link: http://support.apple.com/kb/dl926

mac: http://support.apple.com/kb/dl851

Comment: that would be great - but aparently te Configuration Utility doesn't work on Windows Vista / 7 for uploading IPA files. I keep getting kAMDReceiveMessageError errormessages when trying

Comment: we have successfully used it on serveral vista and win7 boxes. you have to add the version into the apps tab first and then should be able to install it on the devices.